# How to clear form when the user enters zip code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to javascript and need help with implementing the following function: when the user enters a zipcode, any other entries of the form are erased and the zip code is used to look up an address.

How would I do that? The following is code I am using to get location for near by urgentcare areas:

```
(
function(){
    var $scope, $location;
    var urgentCareApp = angular.module('urgentCareApp',['ui.bootstrap']);

    urgentCareApp.controller('UrgentCareController',function($scope,$http,$location,anchorSmoothScroll){
        $scope.Lang = 'initVal';
        $scope.ShowResults = false;
        $scope.ShowDesc = true;
        $scope.NoResults = false;
        $scope.currentPage = 1;
        $scope.maxPageNumbersToShow = 10;
        $scope.formModel = {};
        $scope.searchMode = 0;
        $scope.miles =  [{'value':'5'},{'value':'10'},{'value':'15'},{'value':'20' }];
        $scope.searchParam = {};

        $scope.searchParam.Distance = $scope.miles[0];
        console.log($scope.searchParam.Distance);
        //$scope.searchParam.Specialty = $scope.Specialties[0];

        $scope.GetCurrentZip = function (){
            try{
                var lon, lat;
                console.log('starting geoposition code.');
                if("geolocation" in navigator){
                    window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos){
                        lat = pos.coords.latitude.toFixed(3);
                        lon = pos.coords.longitude.toFixed(3);
                        console.log(lat + ' ' + lon);
                        $http.get("/remote/ReturnCurrentZipcode.cfm?Lat=" + lat + "&Lon=" + lon)
                        .success(function(response){
                            console.log('Response: ' + response);
                            $scope.searchParam.Zip = response;
                            console.log('object set');
                        })
                    })
                }
                else{ console.log('No geolocation'); }
            }
            catch(err) { console.log(err.message); }
        }

        $scope.GetCityList = function (){
            try{
                $http.get("/remote/ReturnUrgentCareCityList.cfm")
                    .success(function(response){
                        $scope.Cities = response.Cities;
                    })
            }
            catch(err){}
        }

        $scope.SearchUrgentCare = function(searchParam){
            try{
                $scope.searchMode = 1;
                var queryString='';
                if($scope.formModel && $scope.formModel !== searchParam){
                    $scope.resultsCount = 0;
                    currentPage = 1;
                }
                if(searchParam){
                    $scope.formModel = searchParam;
                    for(var param in searchParam){
                        console.log(param + ' ' + searchParam.hasOwnProperty(param) + ' ' + searchParam[param]);
                        if(searchParam.hasOwnProperty(param)){
                            var paramValue = searchParam[param].value ? searchParam[param].value.trim() : searchParam[param].trim();
                            if (paramValue.length > 0)
                                queryString += param + '=' + paramValue + '&';
                        }
                    }
                }
                console.log(queryString);
                queryString= '?' + queryString + 'currentpage=' + $scope.currentPage;

                $http.get("/remote/ReturnUrgentCareList.cfm" + queryString)
                .success(function(response){
                    $scope.urgentCareCenters = response.UrgentCareCenters;
                    $scope.resultsCount = response.rowCount;
                    if (!$scope.urgentCareCenters){
                            $scope.NoResults = true;
                            $scope.ShowResults = false;
                            $scope.ShowDesc = false;
                        }
                    else{
                            $scope.NoResults = false;
                            $scope.ShowResults = true;
                            $scope.ShowDesc = false;
                        }
                })
            }
            catch(err){ alert('No response.: ' + err.message); }
        }

        $scope.$watchGroup(['currentPage'], function(){
            try{
                if($scope.searchMode == 1){
                    $scope.SearchUrgentCare($scope.formModel);
                    }
            }
            catch(err){}
        });


        $scope.GetCityList();
        $scope.GetCurrentZip();

        $scope.gotoElement = function (eID){
            var browserWidth = screen.availWidth;
            if (browserWidth < 768)
                anchorSmoothScroll.scrollTo(eID);
        };

    });

    urgentCareApp.service('anchorSmoothScroll', function(){
        this.scrollTo = function(eID) {

            // This scrolling function 
            // is from http://www.itnewb.com/tutorial/Creating-the-Smooth-Scroll-Effect-with-JavaScript

            var startY = currentYPosition();
            var stopY = elmYPosition(eID);
            var distance = stopY > startY ? stopY - startY : startY - stopY;
            if (distance < 100) {
                scrollTo(0, stopY); return;
            }
            var speed = Math.round(distance / 100);
            if (speed >= 20) speed = 20;
            var step = Math.round(distance / 25);
            var leapY = stopY > startY ? startY + step : startY - step;
            var timer = 0;
            if (stopY > startY) {
                for ( var i=startY; i<stopY; i+=step ) {
                    setTimeout("window.scrollTo(0, "+leapY+")", timer * speed);
                    leapY += step; if (leapY > stopY) leapY = stopY; timer++;
                } return;
            }
            for ( var i=startY; i>stopY; i-=step ) {
                setTimeout("window.scrollTo(0, "+leapY+")", timer * speed);
                leapY -= step; if (leapY < stopY) leapY = stopY; timer++;
            }

            function currentYPosition() {
                // Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                if (self.pageYOffset) return self.pageYOffset;
                // Internet Explorer 6 - standards mode
                if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop)
                    return document.documentElement.scrollTop;
                // Internet Explorer 6, 7 and 8
                if (document.body.scrollTop) return document.body.scrollTop;
                return 0;
            }

            function elmYPosition(eID) {
                var elm = document.getElementById(eID);
                var y = elm.offsetTop;
                var node = elm;
                while (node.offsetParent && node.offsetParent != document.body) {
                    node = node.offsetParent;
                    y += node.offsetTop;
                } return y;
            }
        };
    });

    urgentCareApp.directive('allowPattern',[allowPatternDirective]);
    function allowPatternDirective(){
        return{
            restrict: "A",
            compile: function(tElement, tAttrs){
                return function(scope, element, attrs){
                    element.bind("keypress", function(event){
                        var keyCode = event.which || event.keyCode;
                        var keyCodeChar = String.fromCharCode(keyCode);

                        if(!keyCodeChar.match(new RegExp(attrs.allowPattern, "i"))){
                            event.preventDefault();
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    urgentCareApp.filter('PhoneNumber', function(){
    return function(phoneNumber){
        var dash = '-';
        if(phoneNumber){
            var pn = phoneNumber;
            pn = [pn.slice(0, 6), dash, pn.slice(6)].join('');
            pn = [pn.slice(0, 3), dash, pn.slice(3)].join('');
            return pn;
            }
        return phoneNumber;
        }
    });

})();
```

The Form:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <form name="UrgentCareSearch" ng-submit="SearchUrgentCare(searchParam);" novalidate="" role="form">
            <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" id="urgentcare" ng-model="searchParam.UrgentCareName" placeholder="Urgent Care Name" type="text" /></div>

            <div class="form-group"><select class="form-control" id="city" ng-model="searchParam.City" ng-options="City.value for City in Cities"><option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">City</option> </select></div>

            <hr />
            <div style="margin-top:-10px; margin-bottom:10px; text-align:center; font-size:8pt! important">* or Search by Zip code radius *</div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-7 no-right-padding">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group"><select class="form-control" name="distance" ng-model="searchParam.Distance" ng-options="mile.value for mile in miles"></select>

                            <div class="input-group-addon">miles</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-5 no-left-padding">
                    <div class="form-group"><input allow-pattern="[\d\W]" class="form-control" id="zip" maxlength="5" ng-model="searchParam.Zip" placeholder="Zip code" type="text" /></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group"><input class="btn btn-warning btn-block" ng-click="gotoElement('SearchResultsAnchor');" type="submit" value="Search" /></div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is your form?..

Comment: Just added the form

Comment: I want to clear all fields if the user has entered a zip code. When that occurs, then it should display near by location

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about what you're trying to do, but for sure you can use [**`ngChange`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive, so when the user types anything to `Zip` you can do what you want in your controller.

See this **demo**:

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";
  angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
      $scope.reset = function() {
        // If you just want to clear the fields do it:
        var zip = angular.copy($scope.searchParam.Zip);
        $scope.searchParam = {};
        $scope.searchParam.Zip = zip;
      }
    });
})();
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <form name="UrgentCareSearch" ng-submit="SearchUrgentCare(searchParam);" novalidate="" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" id="urgentcare" ng-model="searchParam.UrgentCareName" placeholder="Urgent Care Name" type="text" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <select class="form-control" id="city" ng-model="searchParam.City" ng-options="City.value for City in Cities">
            <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">City</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <hr />
        <div style="margin-top:-10px; margin-bottom:10px; text-align:center; font-size:8pt! important">* or Search by Zip code radius *</div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-7 no-right-padding">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="input-group">
                <select class="form-control" name="distance" ng-model="searchParam.Distance" ng-options="mile.value for mile in miles"></select>

                <div class="input-group-addon">miles</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-5 no-left-padding">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input allow-pattern="[\d\W]" class="form-control" id="zip" maxlength="5" ng-model="searchParam.Zip" placeholder="Zip code" ng-change="reset()" type="text" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="btn btn-warning btn-block" ng-click="gotoElement('SearchResultsAnchor');" type="submit" value="Search" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What are you expecting it to do? Tell me.

Comment: I commented becaused I don't know what you want. Maybe you want just to clear all fields or do a `$http.get` to fill all fields, what do you want finally?

Comment: Okay so when the user enters the zip code, the rest of the form is left blank. Meaning the user will only be searching a near by location based on zip code

Comment: See it now, please.

Comment: Thank You. Sorry for being such a noob. I appreciate you help and sorry to ask one more thing, but do you know a good book I can reference to get better acquinted with javascript?

Comment: Pleasure to help:)  Can you accept the answer? By the way, there are some books: http://tutorialzine.com/2015/05/15-awesome-and-free-javascript-books/

Comment: Thank you so much. This code would go below where is checking if the user has entered a zip code correct

Comment: Where would this code go in? Would it go the the js file where it is looking up the city, state and so on or in the html file?

Comment: In your controller JS. And don't forget to add it: `ng-change="reset()"` in your *Zip* `input`.

Comment: I tried adding the code into the controller and I made the change in the form but it does not clear the other fields minus the miles

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117467/discussion-between-developer033-and-roberto-flores).

Comment: Yeah I looked over what I am doing wrong and I look at the console, it is not recognizing the ng-change, would their be a reason why? I tested it by doing a console.log('hi') and it didnt display in the console

Answer (score -1):

you should either use angular $scope.$watch or ng-change directive
for example if i want do to something when the variable $scope.varA changes
you can use:

```
$scope.$watch("varA", function(){
     //my code 
     //in your case (type searchParams.Zip where i wrote varA)
     var zip = $scope.searchParams.Zip; //keep before cleaning
     $scope.searchParams = {};
     $scope.searchParams.Zip = zip;
});
```

or declare a angular function and use ng-change directive on the html input where you used ng-model for the zip code, (add this as attribute: ng-change="clean_form();")

```
$scope.clean_form = function(){
    var zip = $scope.searchParams.Zip;
    $scope.searchParams =  {};
    $scope.searchParams.Zip = zip;
};
```

the form cleaning code comes from developer033, i just wanted to show you how you could cause that code to happen

Comment: note that angularJS two-way binding will clear the inputs when you use $scope.searchParams = {};

Comment: What's the difference of my answer?

Comment: you didn't suggest $scope.$watch?

Comment: or i didn't see it

Comment: i can delete the ng-change part if it bothers you

Comment: Hello all, during the weekend, I tried your approach and yet it does not work. I am not sure what I am doing wrong